# Browser não reconhece 'else' javascript

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, else

Olá ,

Estou estudando JavaScript e no curso o professor pediu para programar um contador de acordo com o que ele pediu, e para fixar o conteudo eu quero fazer sem ver a resposta dele, porém, no browser aparece o seguinte erro: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else' (at script.js:21:11)', mas eu não vi erro nenhum no meu código, eu programei o if/else de acordo com o que aprendi mas não funciona. O código deve fazer a contagem de acordo com os valores que foram colocados nos inputs de 'inicio' e 'fim', e ir pulando de acordo com o valor colocado em 'passo', porém se não tiver valor ou for igual a '0' aparece uma mensagem 'impossivel contar', mas se o passo for igual a '0' vai aparecer a mesma mensagem porém vai levar em consideração o valor '1' e o valor vai ser adicionado. Mas estou com esse erro :/

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

```
    function submitar() {
    var inicio = Number(document.querySelector('input#inicio').value)
    var fim = Number(document.querySelector('input#fim').value)
    var passo = Number(document.querySelector('input#passo').value)
    var res = document.querySelector('div#res')

    var img = document.createElement('img')
        img.setAttribute('src', 'imagens/mao.png')

    res.innerHTML = 'Contando: '

    if (inicio === '' || fim == '' || passo === '') {
        res.innerHTML = 'Impossivel contar'
    } else if (passo == '0') {
        alert('Impossivel contar. Considerando passo 1')
        passo = passo + 1    
            while(inicio <= fim){
        res.append(inicio + ' , ')
            console.log(inicio)
        inicio += passo
        } else {
            while(inicio <= fim){
        res.append(inicio + ' , ')
            console.log(inicio)
        inicio += passo
        }
    }
}
```

```
<header>
    <h1>Vamos contar</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <div>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    Inicio:
                    <input type="number" name="inicio" id="inicio">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Fim: 
                    <input type="number" name="fim" id="fim">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Passo: 
                    <input type="number" name="passo" id="passo">
                </p>
                <input type="button" id="submit" 
               onclick="submitar()" value="Contar">
            </fieldset> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="res">
      Preparando a contagem...
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; Cristian Bispo</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Esse erro está acontecendo porque você esqueceu de fechar o primeiro `while`.

Veja o código funcionando abaixo:

```js
function submitar() {
    var inicio = Number(document.querySelector('input#inicio').value)
    var fim = Number(document.querySelector('input#fim').value)
    var passo = Number(document.querySelector('input#passo').value)
    var res = document.querySelector('div#res')

    var img = document.createElement('img')
        img.setAttribute('src', 'imagens/mao.png')

    res.innerHTML = 'Contando: '

    if (inicio === '' || fim == '' || passo === '') {
        res.innerHTML = 'Impossivel contar'
    } else if (passo == '0') {
        alert('Impossivel contar. Considerando passo 1')
        passo = passo + 1    
        while(inicio <= fim){
            res.append(inicio + ' , ')
            console.log(inicio)
            inicio += passo
        } // <-- Faltou esse fechamento do while
    }else {
        while(inicio <= fim){
            res.append(inicio + ' , ')
            console.log(inicio)
            inicio += passo
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Vamos contar</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <div>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    Inicio:
                    <input type="number" name="inicio" id="inicio">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Fim: 
                    <input type="number" name="fim" id="fim">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Passo: 
                    <input type="number" name="passo" id="passo">
                </p>
                <input type="button" id="submit" 
               onclick="submitar()" value="Contar">
            </fieldset> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="res">
      Preparando a contagem...
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; Cristian Bispo</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Caramba .. chega fico com vergonha com um errinho pequeno desse, rsrs'. Me desculpe, estou começando agora e nem percebi, e o browser apontou pra linha errada rsrsrs'. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! deu certo. :D

Comment: Esses erros bobos são os que pegam a gente mesmo! Acontece com todo mundo! Sucesso para você!